# How to ignore element height without float?

Tags: css

Alright, so we have this markup:

```
<div class="die-control">
  <div class="symbol yellow"></div>
  <label for="yellow">yellow</label>
  <a class="quantity-control up" href="#">+</a>
  <input name="yellow">
  <a class="quantity-control down" href="#">-</a>
</div>

<div class="die-control">
  <div class="symbol green"></div>
  <label for="green">green</label>
  <a class="quantity-control up" href="#">+</a>
  <input name="green">
  <a class="quantity-control down" href="#">-</a>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.die-control {
   width: calc(100% / 3);
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.symbol.yellow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -7px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: #E9D23F;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.symbol.yellow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  top: -10px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #E9D23F;
}

.symbol.green {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #4F6441;
  top: -5px;
}

.symbol.green::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: -15px;
   top: 20px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border: 15px solid transparent;
   border-top: 20px solid #4F6441;
 }
```

The symbol classes are different heights. So when the the `.control` elements are placed side by side, the `input` elements are not aligned horizontally. If I make the the `.symbol` elements `float: left;`, then their height is ignored and the `input` elements are aligned.  But, I don't want them to float left.

Is there a way to achieve that effect without floating the symbols?

Comment: You are required to show a minimum example of the markup that illustrates the problem. Pseudo code is no help.

Comment: That is valid markup in my template language.  Added the `pug` tag to clarify.

Comment: You are showing CSS only. We need the HTML  and any CSS related to that. Otherwise we have no knowledge of the context of all that which can be affecting this. What is `.control` element? What is the `.symbox` element?

Comment: @dyeje no it isn't http://i.imgur.com/QXl5qqs.png You should post the rendered HTML. You're really limiting the # of people that can/will help by posting the pug markup. This should create some really simple HTML. We also need to see the CSS you've tried.

Comment: Yea, the ::after isn't because I just added it to clarify with the answer below.  Sorry, I thought the `pug` code was universally understood.  I will edit the question.

Comment: The only reason I know pug exists is because I saw someone ask about it a couple of weeks ago. I know nothing about it other than it exists and I've been doing this for 13 years.

Comment: @dyeje thanks. FYI, we shouldn't have to work or make guesses/assumptions just to reproduce the problem in your question. That's your responsibility to provide it to us.

Comment: Updated with plain HTML and CSS.  My intent was to include as little noise as possible in the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @dyeje great. Your CSS is incredibly relevant to the question. Just the pug markup would leave us with a ton of guesswork, and probably waste a lot of one another's time. From the http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: Mimicking the layout that results from floating the symbols left, is this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWZqwa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to  `.die-control` and erase the `float:left` in its rule:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMKGrB

Comment: This worked well, any chance you add some explanation on why?  Will accept either way.

Comment: the `.die-control` containers are the wrappers for everything in them. If you make them inline-blocks, their content is aligned along its baseline (`inline`would work the same way, but in this case you couldn't define a width). Since also all the content containers are inline-blocks, the baseline-alignment works across all elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try use display: inline

Comment: This would work!  But, I'm using some pseudo element stuff and it breaks the look.  Added a clarification.